# How to trigger arrowkey presses in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In chrome(windows), I can capture keypresses on characters, but not on the arrowkeys. See sample-code below:

```js
$('body').on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log('Only works on charcters, in chrome')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I capture arrow-key-presses?

Comment: maybe you should use another selector like `document`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `keypress` to `keyup`:

```js
$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log('Works on everything :)')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `keydown` is working fine

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log('Only works on charcters, in chrome')
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/35/)

Answer (score 1):

I really like this module for key press triggers:

https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster

It really reduces the amount of boilerplate code you need to write when working with key presses.

```
// define short of 'down'
key('down', function(){ alert('you pressed down') });
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I capture arrow-key-presses?

Use `e.keyCode` to detect which key is pressed.

Like this :

```js
$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == '38') {
         alert("up arrow");
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
         alert("down arrow");
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
         alert("left arrow");
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
         alert("right arrow");
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```